# pip installation error "No such file or directory: setup.py"

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, installation

I'm getting installation error because pip couldn't find setup.py.

```sh
sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I get this error message.

```sh
Downloading/unpacking https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Downloading tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl (10.9Mb): 10.9Mb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-GdGgbz-build/setup.py'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-GdGgbz-build/setup.py'
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the output of `sudo pip --version`?

Comment: pip 1.1 from /home/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Comment: Are you in a virtualenv? If so, why are you using `sudo`? Anyway, try updating `pip`

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 and get the same error when installing tensorflow. The output of `sudo pip --version` is `pip 1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`. I have not used `sudo` in the installation process.

Comment: Have you reported the problem to the issues list on the tensorflow github? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

Comment: I have just reported my problem on tensorflow github.

Comment: From tensorflow github's answer, this issue is a duplicate of the issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/56) and upgrading pip to the latest version would solve this issue.

Comment: I finally confirm that after using Ubuntu 15.10 desktop amd64 with python 2.7.10, python-dev and pip 1.5.6, tensorflow will be successfully installed using the pip method.

Comment: `pip 19.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-19.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)` I have this pip version. But, I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 24):

from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/56

> The command to type is **"pip install --upgrade pip"**, and this should be
>   added to the instructions right after where they tell the user to
>   **"source bin/activate"**

Comment: for python3 you can use pip3 install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 3):

Try upgrade protobuf with pip install:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade protobuf 
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2-cp27-none-any.whl
```

worked for me. The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) has provided many solutions for various installation problems.

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow requires python -V 2.7. Since, lot of machine use the stable 2.6 version of python for their system build I would recommend parallel/alternative install of python 2.7. Then you can install pip with 2.7 version python interpreter. Please see below:

```
#sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
#sudo python2.7 ez_setup.py
#easy_install-2.7 pip
#sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 64bits.
I solve this issue by:

```
mkdir -p ~/code/download/lib/tensorflow/
cd ~/code/download/lib/tensorflow/
virtualenv --system-site-packages tensorflow_for_ubuntu12_04_64bit_python2_7
source tensorflow_for_ubuntu12_04_64bit_python2_7/bin/activate
cd tensorflow_for_ubuntu12_04_64bit_python2_7
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

the filename you are running sdist with must be named `setup.py`
running the file as say `setup_something.py` will fail