# Installing module from GitHub through Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

My first time trying to install something from GitHub, but couldn't find a simple solution after searching here and on google.

I'm using Jupyter notebook and trying to install this module:

https://github.com/Expt-David/NumSchrodingerEq

i've tried to write this inside the notebook:

```
!pip install git+git://github.com/Expt-David/NumSchrodingerEq.git
```

but i'm getting the following error:

```
Collecting git+git://github.com/Expt-David/NumSchrodingerEq.git
  Cloning git://github.com/Expt-David/NumSchrodingerEq.git to c:\users\greatg~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-1w_dpw43-build
  Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q git://github.com/Expt-David/NumSchrodingerEq.git C:\Users\GREATG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-1w_dpw43-build
Cannot find command 'git'
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

**EDIT**

Seems that installing git again and manually delete the path and edit myself worked for that issue, but now i'm getting:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/Expt-David/NumSchrodingerEq.git
  Cloning https://github.com/Expt-David/NumSchrodingerEq.git to c:\users\greatg~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-zpuki8tu-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "d:\anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 454, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\GREATG~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-zpuki8tu-build\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\GREATG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-zpuki8tu-build\
```

And I have setuptools installed and updated.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have git installed on your system. Install git. The error is specifying it: `Cannot find command 'git'`

Comment: Install hit on your system and if already then add it to path

Comment: I have git desktop (for Windows) installed, but still getting that error. should I import it to the notebook somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you run your Jupyter Notebook from a session where PATH does include the path to your Git installation.

And [check out pip issue 2109](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2109#issuecomment-65879347):

In my case the problem was the way I had the path to git defined in my path environment on windows.

> the function find_command declared in `pip.util` fails in handle paths with quote, like:

```
PATH=...;c:\python27\scripts;"c:\Program Files\git\cmd";C:\Tcl\bin;...
```

> when it appends the `git.exe` filename to check its existence it keeps the " symbol and the check fails.

That should be fixed in recent version of pip, but again, double-check your `%PATH%`.

---

If that still fails, try with a simplified path, and Git installed in a short PATH without space:

- use the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (uncompress Git 2.13 [`PortableGit-2.13.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.13.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.13.2-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, for instance in `C:\Git2.13.2`)
- set a simplified `PATH`.

Regarding the `PATH` issue, type (in a `CMD`):

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\Git2.13.2
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Add to that `PATH` what you need for python/pip.
Then try again.

---

For your second error message, consider "[pip installation error “No such file or directory: `setup.py`”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33623453/6309)", and double-check your version of Python: `pip` is for python 2. `pip3` is for python 3.

Comment: @ValientProcess What your PATH does look like? Can you type `git version` from the command line?

Comment: the path is okay (without "), but now i'm getting another error of \Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\GREATG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-zpuki8tu-build\

Comment: @ValientProcess OK. I have edited the answer to propose an alternative for you to test. (for your first problem).