# Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out

Tags: git, github, proxy, timeout, solution

I tried all solution but it can not resolved.

I have a problem with my program, when I push a repository to github. I always get this error:

> Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out.

I don't use any proxy. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't use any proxy

Agreed but check if:

- you still have an environment variable http(s)_proxy (uper or lowercase)
- you are seeing that error from an [IDE like Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/4833/git-failed-with-a-fatal-error.html) where copying the binaries from the "`<VS_INSTALL>\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\`" folder to the "`<VS_INSTALL>\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\libexec\git-core\`" folder can resolve the issue
- you are still seeing the error after unzipping/installing the latest Git and using a [simplified PATH (as seen here, if you are on Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878018/6309)

Comment: no, i am using commang line (Git Bash here). And i do not see any environment variable in my computer. Does it about window firewall or anything like antivirus program ? Sorry about my bad english !

Comment: Whic OS anf Git version are you using?

Comment: Window 8.1 and latest Git version 2.13.2

Comment: i will ! Thank you so much !