# wget2 - ./bootstrap - '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: git, wget, bootstrapping

I'm trying to compile the code from wget2 into an exe.

First I downloaded the files from here:
https://github.com/rockdaboot/wget2

I installed Nodejs v8.2.1

Then started following the instructions here:
https://github.com/rockdaboot/wget2

I'm currently stuck at the ./bootstrap command listed under "Build from git".

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2.git
cd wget2
./bootstrap
# on shell failure try 'bash ./bootstrap'
```

git clone works fine and I can cd to the wget2 directory but when I type ./bootstrap I get this error:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

How do I make this command work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That type of command is supposed to by executed in a bash, not in a CMD where './' is not interpreted correctly.

You can try as a mingw bash the one [provided by Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases): just unzip [`PortableGit-2.13.3-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.13.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.13.3-64-bit.7z.exe) and [add Git to your PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878018/6309)

```
set GH=C:\Git2.13.3
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then you can type: `bash`. And execute the suggested commands.