# Error starting Git Bash in windows 7

Tags: windows, git, bash

When start `git bash`, I get this error:

```
[main] bash 8176 child_copy: stack write copy failed, 0xFFFFBE50..0x1000                                                  00000, done 2002650816, windows pid 11128, Win32 error 5
518 [main] bash 8176 fork: child 10232 - pid 10232, exitval 0x103, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Anyone know how solved this error?

Comment: this is not right type of question for this site.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally associated with Cygwin errors, meaning you have Git *and* Cygwin installed, the latter causing issue for the former.

Try again, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878018/6309), with a CMD session where you set a simplified PATH:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then type `git bash`.