# Git clone is slow

Tags: git, windows-10

I am trying to clone from an url. Repository is huge(7-8gbs). I have 100Mbps broadband speed. My mobile hotspot has a speed of 3-4Mbps. Speed of cloning in mobile is close to 1Mbps whereas using broadband it falls down to 200-400Kbps. What can be the reason? Am I missing any configuration?

Whether I use a tortoise git or command line the speed is same in both the case.

Downloading other things stuffs works perfectly fine in my broadband.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git clone in windows much slower than in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768893/git-clone-in-windows-much-slower-than-in-linux) It contains a broad description of what is going on. On which OS are you? The bottleneck might be creation of the file system, not the bandwith of WiFi

Comment: I am on windows 10. I have already tried the step said in the above link.

Comment: Oh I see! I'll retract the flag. When this is the case, try to include your researched links in the question body :)

Comment: This sounds more like a network issue than a git issue (or anything related to your computer). Maybe your mobile ISP has a better network route to the target server than your broadband connection. I bet on serverfault they may be able to help you do some troubleshooting. Maybe try tracert to see if the paths differ.