# Failed to connect to repository: returned status code 128:stdout

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

When using my Git client, I get:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "c:\program files \git\bin\git.exe Is remote -h ssh://git@git.vehraius.com:7999/dmp/hybris.git HEAD" returned status code 128:stdout
stderr: ssh:connect to host git.vahraius.com port 7999:Connection refused fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have right access and repository exists.
```

Any Pointers?

Comment: "Connection refused" implies that either that server is down or that there's something in the network that's keeping you from getting there.

Comment: Last week i configured SSL Certificate with Port No 443 in bitbucket....and it was working fine. Is it a port issue?

Comment: That's unlikely, since that certificate was for HTTPS connections and this is for SSH.

Comment: Right....but port no was 443...and its showing now 7999....why so?

Comment: Port 443 is for HTTPS. This is SSH, which needs a different port; Bitbucket Server uses 7999 for pushes and pulls over SSH so that you can still use port 22 (the default SSH port) to access the underlying server.

Comment: Thanks for your time Jim!!....What should i do to fix it asap......

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure what ssh private keys are served to your Bitbucket server when trying to access it.
Check the results of:

```
ssh -Tv git@git.vehraius.com
```

Then make sure the corresponding public key is registered in your BitBucket user SSH settings page.

Comment: @SanyamBhatnagar So, what does the `ssh -Tv` shows you?

Comment: Actually putty is not installed...hence not recognizing SSH command.

Comment: @SanyamBhatnagar you don't need putty: ssh is included with Git. Use the right PATH: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779657/6309

Comment: ssh -Tv git@git.<access>.com
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to git.<access>.com [IP] port 22.
debug1: connect to address IP port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host git.<access>.com port 22: Connection refused

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Because ssh connections would be blocked by a proxy.

Comment: Its resolved by creating own user id and password(not ssh). But I have to do from SSH....Any process?

Comment: @SanyamBhatnagar yes, using https with a user/password will work. But for ssh, test if you are allowed to do ssh, with a telnet: https://serverfault.com/a/567302/783