# How to push android project to github with this error is given below?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, git-commit

I have a trouble when I push my project to GitHub:

When I finish commit, the following error will appear:

[image: https://ppt.cc/fCVeHx]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try again launching Android Studio from a CMD where you have set a simplified PATH, putting your Git for Windows installation first.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779657/6309) as an example:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

set PATH=%PATH%;/path/to/Android Studio/bin
```

Make sure you have uncompressed the [latest Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (like [`PortableGit-2.15.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.15.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.15.0-64-bit.7z.exe)) anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the URL is not correct. Make sure to update your VCS plugin in Android Studio