# 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command [Windows]

Tags: github

Not a duplicate of

> ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

I've set up my github repository, downloaded Github Desktop, but I can't figure out how to upload files to the repo.

[Here are Github's instructions for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIvwG.png)

I've done the "quick set up", and have set up github Desktop on my computer. However, I can't get the command line repo setup to work. Whenever I type out a git command, it gives the above error. I've tried to research why this happens, but the only relevant source (linked above) gave instructions regarding a past version of the github app.

I know this is probably very simple, but I'm quite new and can't find out what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somehow the GitHub Destop did not add an internal Git to your PATH, you can do so manually with the latest [Git for Windows release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

Uncompress the archive [`PortableGit-2.15.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.15.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.15.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want and [add it to your `PATH` (as I do here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172186/6309), then launch GitHub Desktop.

Comment: I've downloaded portable git, but I'm not able to add it to my path using the commands in your other post. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You can edit your post with the commands you typed. Also make sure to launch GitHub Desktop from the same CMD session.

Comment: I typed exactly what you had in your other post, line by line, with no changes. Every time I entered, nothing happened.

Comment: You did change the path to git by your actual path for your own git, right?

Comment: No I did not - I have 0 experience with cmd, sorry. My portable git folder is at C:\Users\Adam\Downloads\PortableGit

Comment: Then you can set GH to that path. The rest is unchanged.