# GitLab self hosted ssh authorisation failed

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I carefully follow official [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html) how to connect to self-hosted GitLab from Windows (tried with VisualStudio and Tower).
But connection is not established.

From [Troubleshooting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#troubleshooting) section I run `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.mydomain.com` and get this:

```
matjaz.cof@MatjazCof-PC MINGW64 ~
$ ssh -Tv git@gitlab.mydomain.com
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.mydomain.com [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version ROSSSH
debug1: no match: ROSSSH
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.mydomain.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:hTqVMUtkiM3ngYdEyH4JZ5A7QjY8O3Ih9EFS13AIp84
debug1: Host 'gitlab.mydomain.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@gitlab.mydomain.com's password:
```

It outputs

> No such file or directory

, but my id_rsa.pub exists:

[image: file]

I added my public key to my profile in GitLab: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip`.

My repository https url is: `https://gitlab.mydoamin.com:3000/web/oppis.git` and it works (not sure if port matters), but not with SSH.

**Edited:**
I know path is strange for Windows environment, but I don't know how to fix this. Also when executing `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your.email@example.com" -b 4096` suggested path for saving keys are "strange": `/c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh`, but files are saved. So I though this should work.

**Edited** @TarunLalwani

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -Tv git@gitlab.mydomain
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.mydomain [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version ROSSSH
debug1: no match: ROSSSH
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.mydomain:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:hTqVMUtkiM3ngYdEyH4JZ5A7QjY8O3Ih9EFS13AIp84
debug1: Host 'gitlab.mydomain' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@gitlab.mydomain's password:
```

**Edited** @JuanMellado

I found something strange:

```
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:w3E6UGqM5x3VniG+sKMxOJiTupmX3N4pwWPt6PW9di8 /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Strange is I have `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa` files. (They were create with GitBash `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your.email@example.com" -b 4096`)

So I change `id_rsa.pub` to `id_rsa` and `id_rsa` to `id_dsa`.

Now I get different log (relevant section):

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:w3E6UGqM5x3VniG+sKMxOJiTupmX3N4pwWPt6PW9di8 /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:w3E6UGqM5x3VniG+sKMxOJiTupmX3N4pwWPt6PW9di8
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@gitlab.mydomain's password:
```

Not sure why it tries to send another private key (`id_ecdsa)?

Full log:

```
$ ssh -v -v -v -t git@gitlab.mydomain
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "gitlab.mydomain" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.mydomain [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version ROSSSH
debug1: no match: ROSSSH
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.mydomain:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.mydomain
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,none
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,none
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1018/2048
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:hTqVMUtkiM3ngYdEyH4JZ5A7QjY8O3Ih9EFS13AIp84
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.mydomain
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from *.*.*.*
debug1: Host 'gitlab.mydomain' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1008/2048
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa (0x600061260)
debug2: key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:w3E6UGqM5x3VniG+sKMxOJiTupmX3N4pwWPt6PW9di8 /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:w3E6UGqM5x3VniG+sKMxOJiTupmX3N4pwWPt6PW9di8
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@gitlab.mydomain's password:
```

I can say, I try this on 2 computers, My Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012. Both uses same domain user.

**Edited** @VonC

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin>ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -Tv git@gitlab.mydomain
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.mydomain [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version ROSSSH
debug1: no match: ROSSSH
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.mydomain:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:hTqVMUtkiM3ngYdEyH4JZ5A7QjY8O3Ih9EFS13AIp84
debug1: Host 'gitlab.mydomain' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@gitlab.mydomain's password:
```

Strange is that `/c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/id_rsa` is not found, but `/c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/known_hosts` is.
I have 3 files in `c:\Users\matjaz.cof\.ssh\`:

- id_dsa
- id_rsa
- known_hosts

**Edited** @TarunLalwani

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin>ls -al /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/
total 25
drwxr-xr-x 1 matjaz.cof 1049089    0 Feb 20 08:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 matjaz.cof 1049089    0 Feb 16 09:24 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 matjaz.cof 1049089 3243 Feb 20 08:45 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 matjaz.cof 1049089  744 Feb 20 08:45 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 matjaz.cof 1049089  410 Feb 20 08:49 known_hosts
```

Comment: Looks like `/c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh` is not the way to reach your `c:\Users\matjaz.cof\.ssh` directory.

Comment: I agree, but don't know how to solve it, if this is actually the problem.

Comment: Can you try `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -Tv git@gitlab.mydomain.com`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I edited my question with output from you command.

Comment: What is the value of the environment variable GIT_SSH?

Comment: @VonC It doesn't exist on either computer (windows 10, server 2012). `Get-ChildItem Env:` does not return GIT_SSH.

Comment: @Makla Can you try the same ssh command in a CMD (not Powershell or gitposh or ...), with a simlpified PATH? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779657/6309)

Comment: @VonC I edit my question. Look `Edited @VonC`

Comment: You should have id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. Try again your ssh-keygen command, and make sure to copy the content of id_rsa.pub in the remote server ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys. Do not copy/rename id_rsa.pub into id_rsa.

Comment: can you do a `ls -al /c/Users/matjaz.cof/.ssh/` and add that also to your question.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Added as `Edited @TarunLalwani`

Comment: Please join this chatroom https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165470/gitlab-self-hosted-ssh-authorisation-failed

Comment: @VonC I created new keys with `ssh-keygen`. I also uploaded content of `.pub` to GitLab [documentation point 5.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair). But I didn't understand copying to remote. Remote is Linux inside VM VirtualBox. It has only user root. Is this step really necessary? In documentation there is no such step mentioned.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I forget to click save. I also join the room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in firewall. I forget to set [Harpin NAT](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT).

My firewall allowed me to connect to port 22. I also route port 22 to GitLab machine IP. But forget to set `Harpin NAT`.

*That means If my public IP is 1.2.3.4(gitlab.mydomain.com) I could connect to gitlab.mydomain.com from any public IP except (1.2.3.4).*

Router didn't know what to do with packets, because LAN machine tries to connect to another LAN machine via the external IP address. ([WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning))

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on chat, this turns out to be a firewall problem at your office. Your firewall probably blocks outgoing connections on port 22 to other server.

This is the main reason for not being able to reach to the SSH server and that is why it works from your home network and not from office

Comment: I award your answer, because I wanted to thank you for your help. With you and @VonC trying to solve my problem I figure it out what was the problem. I write my own answer which actually solves my problem. Thank you both.