# unable to read config file '%USERPROFILES%/.gitconfig': No such file or directory

Tags: git

> $ git config --list --global
>
> fatal: unable to read config file '%USERPROFILES%/.gitconfig': No
>   such file or directory

`.gitconfig` is already present in the `%USERPROFILES%`

But it keeps giving me the above message.

Answer (score 0):

`%USERPROFILES%` does not exist.
`%USERPROFILE%` does.

Try and re-install [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), possibly through the [portable version](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.20.0-rc1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.20.0.rc1.windows.1-64-bit.7z.exe) (an archive you can uncompress anywhere you want, and which [is not a malware](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/03fe07c9f143cca4fc8eab5a7210ee70b48f8a3c1c9687e1c8d67e8f403908de/detection)), and a [simplified `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779657/6309). Then check in that session (the one with said simplified path) if the issue persists.