# Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed git AND 'error launching git: The filename or extension is too long.'

Tags: git, git-bash, visual-studio-code

I have looked at most of the posts describing the first error on the title : **"Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed git"**.

Nevertheless, I believe that the second error **"error launching git: The filename or extension is too long."** generates the first one.

Could you help me?

1. Git works while using "Git Bash"
2. VS Code indicates that *git not found. install it or configure it using **'git.path'***
   [image: vscode git not found. install it or configure it using 'git.path']
3. VS Code indicates that **VSCODE : no source control providers registered**
   [image: VSCODE : no source control providers registered]
4. The *.vscode/settings.json* contains **"git.path": "c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe"**
   [image]

   5. Running on the *VSCode Terminal* the command *Git* or *Git version* generates the same error : **error launching git: The filename or extension is too long.**
   6. **Git works perfectly if using Git bash**
      [image: Git works perfectly if using Git bash]

Any idea?

Thank you for the time invested!

Comment: I think that the error you get when you exceed the max PATH length. Try to simplify the PATH using variables. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778066/threadscopes-gettext-sh-file-interferes-with-git-on-windows/45779657#45779657

Comment: I have simplified the path to a minimum but the error remains "error launching git: The filename or extension is too long"

Path=c:\Progra~1\Git\usr\bin;c:\Progra~1\Git\bin;C:\App\GitLFS;C:\Progra~1\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution: find the Git version that works on my computer

### Where is Git on my computer?

I have executed the command `where git` on Windows Command prompt :

```
C:\Users\<my-user>where git
c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

I have executed the command `where git` on GIT BASH :

```
$ where git
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

### Which version of Git runs on my computer?

I have executed the command `git --version` on `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` :

```
$ "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" --version
error launching git: The filename or extension is too long.
```

I have executed the command `git --version` on `Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe` :

```
$ "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe" --version
git version 2.20.1.windows.1
```

### First conclusion: 2 versions of Git do not work on my computer

**Git Bash has a third version of git installed which works on my computer in this path `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe`**

### I have adapted the settings on Visual Studio Code and Git works again!

Visual Studio Code > File > Preferences > Settings > Search Settings - type git.path > Edit in settings.json

```
{
    "git.path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe", 
   ...
}
```

**Now, Git works again on Visual Studio Code**

Comment: "git.path": "C:\\Users\\<me>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe" works for me.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, it was working fine and suddenly it wasn't anymore.

I noticed it was caused by Xcode updating the git and the user agreement. I had to re-accept it if I wanted to use git from CLI.

So, running `sudo xcodebuild -license` and accepting the license solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your .vscode/settings.json contains "git.path": "c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" with duplicated backslashes (on image `c:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe`).

If you go in VSCode terminal with cd command to c:\Program Files\Git\bin\ and run git.exe have the same error?

Comment: yes, I got the same error if I run "c:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" from the vscode terminal

Answer (score 0):

For MAC, you should rather add below to `settings.json` file

```
"git.path": "/usr/local/git/bin/git"
```

For windows, you should add

```
"git.path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe"
```