# git: 'remote-https' is not a git command - Visual Studio Code Sync

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When trying to use the Synchronize Change button at the bottom left corner of Visual

Studio Code I get a

```
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command
```

The logs show that this:

```
> git pull --tags origin master
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

However, I can still Git pull/push from the Terminal in VS Code. The only thing that causes this error is the Synchronize Change button.
I've reinstalled Git for Windows but it didn't fix the issue.
I can see that git-remote-https.exe is located in

> "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core"

but I'm not sure how VS Code Synchronize Change should reference that.

Answer (score 0):

If you see an error like:

[image]

Check your `%PATH%` first.
In a CMD, type `set path`.

For testing, type in that CMD:

```bash
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set "GH=C:\Program Files\Git"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

Then, still from that CMD, launch VSCode (make sure the other one was closed first)

```
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd"
```

See if the issue persists then.

Another approach is to set `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` in `git.path`, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54731054/6309).