# Add files to .gitignore directly from git shell

Tags: git, echo, gitignore, git-shell

I'm trying to add a specific file to .gitignore directly from git shell.  File to ignore is `token.mat`

If I type:

```
touch .gitignore
```

and then manually open .gitignore with a text editor and add

```
token.mat
```

save and close, it works, git ignores it (when I type git status at the git shell I no longer see token.mat)

However at the git shell if I type:

```
touch .gitignore
echo 'token.mat' >> .gitignore
```

then git does not ignore token.mat, when I type git status I still see it.  However when I open .gitignore with a text edit I see token.mat listed and it looks exactly the same as when I add it manually.

Does anyone know why this is, or how I can add files to .gitignore directly from the git shell?

Thanks for any help in advance!!

Other details:

- Windows 7 Professional, service pack 1
- git version: 2.5.3.windows.1
- text editor: Notepad ++

Comment: does the text editor handle adding/handling indexes of files to git project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your echo did not add a trailing space:

```
echo 'token.mat'>>.gitignore
```

That way, the `.gitignore` should work.

`>>` is for *appending* to the `.gitignore` file, while a single `>` would have *overwritten* it completely.

Also, 2.5 is ancient: unzip [the latest Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), as in [`PortableGit-2.14.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.14.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.14.1-64-bit.7z.exe), anywhere you want, [add it to your `%PATH%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878018/6309), and check again.

Comment: Thanks VonC!  There was no trailing space, but moving up to Git 2.14 did the trick.  One other note, to others trying this solution, I also changed from Git Shell to Git Bash with the upgrade.

Comment: Would like to add that a single '>' overwrites existing data, a double '>>' updates file.

Comment: @afrologicinsect good point. I have included that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is totally correct, but would be incomplete in day to day scenarios as it only add one file to `.gitignore` , to add more than one files to your `.gitignore`

Use the following command :

`echo -e 'file1 \n file2 \n file3 \n' >> .gitignore`

You can use the above command without `touch` this will automatically create a `.gitignore` and add all the files. Make   sure that you include `-e` and `>>`.

Here `-e` serves as the flag so the newline character `\n` is interpreted properly and `>>` appends the content in the `.gitignore` file.

If you need to override an already existing `.gitignore` use `>` instead of `>>`

You can learn more about `echo` [by following this link.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html)