# How does git relate with npm? | npm ERR! Failed using git. | material.angular.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, git, angular-cli

Angular 4 cli, I run this command to install Angular Material (**npm install --save angular/material2-builds angular/cdk-builds**) but it is showing an error as followS:

```
    npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed using git.
    npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
```

For this scenario, I have to install git in my PC or how is git related to npm? How can I solve this issue? Anyway thanks to everyone.

Comment: One of the install scripts probably wants to download some source package from a git repository instead of from npm. Might be because there is no npm package

Comment: Are you sure git is installed correctly? What happens if you type `git help -a` from the command line?

Comment: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You need to install it, the package you are trying to get needs it.

Comment: My question is why i want to install git in my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use a [portable Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (like [`PortableGit-2.14.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.14.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.14.2-64-bit.7z.exe)) I have uncompressed anywhere I want.

Then I write a small `senv.bat` script that will set the PATH for me with the minimum I need, which is:

- a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878018/6309)

  ```
   set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
   set GH=C:\path\to\git
   set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
  ```
- a PATH completed with the minimum you need

  ```
   set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\npm
  ```

> My question is why i want to install git in my server?

That is part of the official `npm` documentation: see "[No Git](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#no-git)".
`npm` can need to clone dependencies from remote Git repos.

Comment: I will update your answer result after testing! Thanks for your great work

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add Git to your **PATH** env variable.

Comment: Can u please explain how to add