# can't build a project with expo (react native and node)

Tags: node.js, git, react-native, npm, expo

When I try to run "expo init my-new-project" in my console i get these errors :

```
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/expo/react-native-maps.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\??\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-13T13_11_19_931Z-debug.log
Process exited with non-zero code: 1
```

I tried everything but this is still happening. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does git relate with npm? | npm ERR! Failed using git. | material.angular.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460142/how-does-git-relate-with-npm-npm-err-failed-using-git-material-angular-io)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+npm+ERR%21+No+git+binary+found+in+%24PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line `No git binary found in $PATH` is telling you that you do not have `git` installed on your Windows machine.

You need to install `git`.

1. Download the latest Git for [Windows installer](https://git-for-windows.github.io/).
2. When you've successfully started the installer, you should see the Git Setup wizard screen. Follow the Next and Finish prompts to complete the installation. The default options are pretty sensible for most users.
3. Open a Command Prompt (or Git Bash if during installation you elected not to use Git from the Windows Command Prompt).
4. Run the following commands to configure your Git username and email using the following commands, replacing Emma's name with your own. These details will be associated with any commits that you create:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Emma Paris"
$ git config --global user.email "eparis@atlassian.com"
```

These instructions are from [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git#windows)

Comment: Tried it but sadly didn't work. Still getting the same errors.