# Sublime Text 3's Gitgutter - Git Version could not be acquired

Tags: git, path, package, sublimetext3, atlassian-sourcetree

I installed Gitgutter's Package on Sublime Text 3, but it doesn't seem to work, I debugged support info and got this:

- Sublime Text 3143
- Platform: windows
- Arch: x32
- GitGutter 1.7.8
- Install via PC: True
- git version could not be acquired!
- mdpopups not installed!
- markdown not installed!
- pygments version could not be acquired!
- jinja2 not installed!

[I also tried re-installing it, and still does not compare the scripts with the current HEAD's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dwuA.png)

I saw that the Gitgutter's implementation was pretty automatic, I don't know if it has something to do with using Sourcetree's Git client. I guess that I should reference the Git's PATH, where could I find it?

Please let me know if there is more required info I may have omitted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th error message comes from [`modules/support.py`](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/blob/e2077c6e006acfd2f060aef03c4ef8f89c4db362/modules/support.py#L42-L48)

```py
def git_version():
    """Read version of git binary."""
    try:
        return git('--version')
    except Exception as exception:
        print('%s: %s' % (PACKAGE, exception))
        return 'git version could not be acquired!'
```

The installation process is described [in issue 452](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/issues/452#issuecomment-331625585)

As mentioned in [issue 455](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/issues/455#issuecomment-333084090):

> With git for windows installed and registered to the PATH and works from console, GitGutter should find it out of the box on Windows.

So try and launch your SBT from a CMD with [a simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878018/6309) to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me solve the problem, I finally found git.exe's path and referenced it on git_binary from Gittgutter's User settings.